# Counting repeated array elements

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to separate my data into train and test slices, but i haven't really fully understand how to work around lists in python. I want to increase the index number of my Y value, after every 50th element. What i was trying to do is to automate this task:

```
img_amount = 50

y = np.asarray([1]*img_amount + [2]*img_amount + [3]*img_amount + [4]*img_amount + [5]*img_amount + [6]*img_amount + [7]*img_amount + [8]*img_amount + [9]*img_amount + [10]*img_amount + [11]*img_amount + [12]*img_amount + [13]*img_amount + [14]*img_amount + [15]*img_amount + [16]*img_amount + [17]*img_amount + [18]*img_amount + [19]*img_amount + [20]*img_amount + [21]*img_amount + [22]*img_amount + [23]*img_amount + [24]*img_amount + [25]*img_amount + [26]*img_amount + [27]*img_amount + [28]*img_amount + [29]*img_amount +[30]*img_amount + [31]*img_amount + [32]*img_amount + [33]*img_amount + [34]*img_amount + [35]*img_amount + [36]*img_amount + [37]*img_amount + [38]*img_amount + [39]*img_amount + [40]*img_amount + [41]*img_amount + [42]*img_amount + [43]*img_amount + [44]*img_amount + [45]*img_amount)
```

Output:

> [ 1  1  1 ... 45 45 45]

rather than writting by hand every index, i am trying to do the same thing by just looping through repeating img_amount, this was what i tried:

```
img_amount = 50
for idx in range(45):
    y = [idx]*img_amount
print(y)
```

Output:

> [44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44,
> 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44,
> 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44]

Basically i was expecting the same output from 1... 45 but it outputs 44, 44, 44...
Instead of having to write [n]*im_amount for every time, i'd like to do so, automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do it.

```py
img_amount = 50
y = []
for idx in range(45):
    # use extend to add the new list to y.
    # also python range(45) starts from 0 , ends at 44.
    y.extend( [idx + 1]*img_amount)
print(y)
```

in your code,

```py
y=[idx]*img_amount
```

is repeatedly assigning a new list to variable name `y` in each `for` loop, so `y` will equal the list of the last loop, which is `[44,44...]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `np.repeat` for this.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(1, 46), 50)
[1, 1, 1, ...., 45, 45, 45]
```